# Unable to determine the principal end of the etaxiDataModel relationship. Multiple added entities may have the same primary key

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

[image: Mapping definitions for SettlementShift]I have been struggling with this problem for some time now and am not able to resolve this. Have read multiple posts and tried several different solutions but nothing has worked. Now I feel like I have come to a stop and really need help with this.

I am using EF 5+ with an DB first and edmx file. I have 3 different tables in my DB:
1. Settlement
2. Cost
3. Shift

Settlement has a collection of both Cost and Shift (with a link table) connected by Association in my edmx file.

[image: Settlement table with Link tables in my DB]
I need to insert a new Settlement in my db with a reference to an already existing Cost and Shift collections. 
Shifts and Costs included in my Settlement entity I am trying to insert contains all there related data and none of those are modified in any way (same as I retrieved from db).
Here in my method of inserting the entity into my db.

```
public bool CreateSettlement(Settlement settlement)
    {
        bool _success;

        var _context = new EtaxiEnteties();// ObjectFactory.Get<IETaxiEntitiesContext>();

            try
            {
                var _newSettlement = new Settlement
                                         {
                                             CreateDate = settlement.CreateDate,
                                             Driver = settlement.Driver,
                                             DriverID = settlement.DriverID,
                                             Car = settlement.Car,
                                             CarID = settlement.CarID,
                                             DocPath = settlement.DocPath
                                         };
                foreach (var _shift in settlement.Shifts)
                {
                    //var _sh = _context.Shifts.Find(_shift.ShiftID);
                    //_context.Entry(_sh).CurrentValues.SetValues(_shift);
                    _newSettlement.Shifts.Add(_shift);
                }

                foreach (var _cost in settlement.Costs)
                {
                    ////var _sh = _context.Costs.Find(_cost.CostID);
                    ////_context.Entry(_sh).CurrentValues.SetValues(_cost);
                    _newSettlement.Costs.Add(_cost);
                }
                _context.Settlements.Add(_newSettlement);

                _success = _context.SaveChanges() > 0;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception(ex.Message);
            }
        return _success;
    }
```

Any help on the issue would be MUCH appreciated.

Here is how I am adding the Cost and Shift to my collection:

I create a Settlement in page:

```
_settlement = new Settlement
                            {
                                CreateDate = DateTime.Now,
                                Driver = _driver,
                                DriverID = _driver.DriverID,
                                Car = _car,
                                CarID = _car.CarID,
                                DocPath = _path
                            };
```

then when I create a pdf file with selected rows from 2 separated grid views:

```
   foreach (GridDataItem _selectedRow in gwShifts.MasterTableView.Items)
            {
                if (_selectedRow.Selected)
                {
                    var _shift =
                        _diaryRepository.GetShiftByID((int) _selectedRow.GetDataKeyValue("ShiftID")).FirstOrDefault();

                    if (_shift != null)
                    {
                        _settlement.Shifts.Add(_shift);
                        _settlementData.Shifts.Add(_shift);
                        _settlementData.SplitPercentace = GetTemplateValue(_selectedRow, "lblSplit");
                        _settlementData.SettlementAmount = GetTemplateValue(_selectedRow, "lblSettlementAmount");

                        if (_settlementData.Shifts != null)
                        {
                            _tableShifts.AddCell(
                                new PdfPCell(
                                    new Phrase(
                                        _settlementData.Shifts.FirstOrDefault().ShiftDate.ToShortDateString(),
                                        _bodyFont)) {Border = 0});
                            _tableShifts.AddCell(
                                new PdfPCell(
                                    new Phrase(
                                        string.Format("{0:c}", _settlementData.Shifts.FirstOrDefault().GrossAmount),
                                        _bodyFont)) {Border = 0});
                            _tableShifts.AddCell(
                                new PdfPCell(
                                    new Phrase(
                                        string.Format("{0:c}", _settlementData.Shifts.FirstOrDefault().MoneyAmount),
                                        _bodyFont)) {Border = 0});
                            _tableShifts.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase(_settlementData.SplitPercentace, _bodyFont))
                                                     {Border = 0});
                            _tableShifts.AddCell(
                                new PdfPCell(new Phrase(_settlementData.SettlementAmount, _boldTableFont))
                                    {Border = 0});

                            _totalAmount.AddRange(new[]
                                                      {
                                                          Convert.ToInt32(
                                                              _settlementData.SettlementAmount.Replace(".", "").
                                                                  Replace(",", "").Replace("kr", ""))
                                                      });
                            _settlementData.Shifts.Remove(_shift);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            var _summaryCell =
                new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Upphæð: " + string.Format("{0:c}", _totalAmount.Sum()), _boldTableFont))
                    {
                        Border = 0,
                        Colspan = 5,
                        HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_RIGHT,
                        Padding = 5,
                        BorderWidthTop = 1
                    };
            _tableShifts.AddCell(_summaryCell);

            if (_totalAmount.Count != 0)
                _totalAmount.Clear();
        }
```

there you see how I add the Shift to this Settlement entity:

```
     var _shift =
                        _diaryRepository.GetShiftByID((int) _selectedRow.GetDataKeyValue("ShiftID")).FirstOrDefault();

                    if (_shift != null)
                    {
                        _settlement.Shifts.Add(_shift);
```

then I send this to the reporistory (see method above)

```
        if(_driverRepository.CreateSettlement(_settlement))
            {
                SetMessage("Uppgjör hefur verið skapað og sent bílstjóra ef e-póstur er skráður á viðkomandi bílstjóra.", "Uppgjör skapað");
                pnlSettlement.Visible = false;
                pnlDocCreation.Visible = false;
                pnlResult.Visible = false;   
            }
```

I also tried to simply add param settlement directly to the context but got similar error.

Comment: Sorry, nothing to do with the question (which I think in itself is good: +1), but I saw what you are doing with catching an exception here and I want to kindly suggest that it may not be ideal to do that.  You are catching the general Exception then making a new general exception with the message from the original.  This means you will not only lose the exception type but the stack trace of the original exception too which can make debugging a whole heap harder.  In this specific case it looks like you would have been better off just not catching anything.

Comment: Hi kmp
I know this :) still //TODO Exception handling. I just put it there so I have something while I am setting this up.

Comment: try adding the `newSettlement` instance to the context before populating the `Shift` and `Cost` collections. If that still fails how/when/where are the underlying `Cost` & `Shift` collections being instantiated?

Comment: Sorry, did not work
Unable to determine the principal end of the 'etaxiDataModel.FK_Car_Account' relationship. Multiple added entities may have the same primary key.

Comment: Can you turn it around? `_shift.Settlement = _newSettlement`

Comment: I need to do it like this: 
 _shift.Settlements = new[] {_newSettlement};

since my relationship is many to many (a link table).

Comment: Ahhh, your diagram is a bit elusive!

Comment: maybe I should change that then ;) 
I am quite new to EF and I am using DB first method. I simply have created the DB in the "Old Fashion Way" and generated my model from that.

Comment: We need to see the mapping definitions.

Comment: Added image above

from Settlement POCO:
  public virtual ICollection<Cost> Costs { get; set; }
  public virtual ICollection<Shift> Shifts { get; set; }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, came up with a "ugly" solution on this..but it is resolved.
Changed the Model to be one(Settlement) -> many(Shift or Cost) relationship.

I create a new Settlement and save this one to the DB. 
Retrieve each Shift and Cost from the DB update SettlementID on each and save these to the DB.

```
 try
        {
            var _newSettlement = new Settlement
                                        {
                                            CreateDate = settlement.CreateDate,
                                            DriverID = settlement.DriverID,
                                            CarID = settlement.CarID,
                                            DocPath = settlement.DocPath
                                        };
            Add(_newSettlement);
            _success = SaveWithSuccess() > 0;

            var _settlement = GetAll().FirstOrDefault(x => x.SettlementID == _newSettlement.SettlementID);

            if (_success)
            {
                foreach (var _shift in settlement.Shifts)
                {
                    var _sh = _diaryRepository.GetShiftByID(_shift.ShiftID).FirstOrDefault();
                    _sh.SettlementID = _settlement.SettlementID;
                    _diaryRepository.UpdateShift(_sh);
                }

                foreach (var _cost in settlement.Costs)
                {
                    var _ch = _costRepository.GetCostByID(_cost.CostID);
                    _ch.SettlementID = _settlement.SettlementID;
                    _costRepository.UpdateCost(_ch);

                }
            }
        }
```

not a pretty one, but it resolves the problem. 
I am not concerned about the DB request load..it will not be that high in this case.

I would think there is a nicer solution to this but I was not able to find it at this time.

Thanks for all your efforts to help :)

Answer (score 0):

I think this has to do with how you're populating the `Shifts` and `Costs` collection. You're trying to add already created records (i.e. they already have their primary key values set) to be saved with the new `Settlement` entity, but I believe that Entity Framework isn't trying to create new ones that are linked to your new `Settlement` entity but rather save them to the table as is. In such a case you would indeed have a situation where multiple entities have the same primary key.

I would try the following (I'll show you using the `Shifts` loop only, but you should be able to apply it to the `Costs` loop as well):

```
foreach (var _shift in settlement.Shifts)
{
  var newShift = new Shift { /*Copy all of the values from _shift here*/ };
  _newSettlement.Shifts.Add(_shift);
  context.Shifts.Add(newShift);
}
```

If that doesn't work I would suggest debugging `Costs` and `Shifts` to make sure that you don't have any duplicates in those collections.

Comment: be sure to set `newShift.SettlementId` to `newSettlement.SettlementId`

Comment: will this not create a new Shift in my DB?

Comment: Did not work..I get double of Shifts (and Cost) when I use this approach

Comment: Did you get the same error that you were getting before? If not, then debug the `Shifts` and `Costs` collection to make sure that there are no duplicates.

Comment: There are no duplicates of Shift and Cost. I never change those entities either. Simply use the data from them.
When I remove _newSettlement.Shifts.Add(_shift); I get no duplicates in my collection. 
I however get en error message:
  Unable to determine the principal end of the 'etaxiDataModel.FK_Shift_Account' relationship. Multiple added entities may have the same primary key.
All Shifts have relationship to Account (ID) and all Shifts selected have the same AccountID (does this matter?)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want new `Shifts` & `Costs` then I can only assume you need to repoint the existing ones to the new `Settlement`

```
foreach (var shift in settlement.Shifts)
{  
    //either
    shift.Settlement = newSettlement;
    //or
    shift.SettlementId = newSettlement.SettlementId;
    //depending on your object model
}
```

---

I've just realised that I have misunderstood the question. There are 2 additional tables not shown in the diagram (Costs & Shifts). The problem is trying to create `SettlementCost` and `SettlementShift` entities that connect Settlement to `Costs\Shifts`.

Comment: `newSettlement.SettlementId` is not an option: it's a new object at that moment.

Comment: Ok, current status: 
Tried this: _shift.Settlements = new[] {_newSettlement};
then I:
 _context.Settlements.Add(_newSettlement);
 _success = _context.SaveChanges() > 0;

it saves the Settlement into DB but no relation to either Shift or Cost

Comment: @GertArnold you're probably right but I didn't assume database generated id's

Comment: @qujck Yeah, could be. Ingimar, I don't recognize qujck's suggestion in your code.

Comment: @Gert Arnold: _shift.Settlements = new[] {_newSettlement}; since I have collections on both sides

Comment: @guick: Yes :) Like I said in my initial question there are 2 Link tables that generate the collection in my Entities. The Link is between Settlement -> Cost and Settlement -> Shift (ID in both cases).